# Variable attribute to set CSS property

Tags: javascript, css

Could I use a variable attribute value to set CSS property? This is because I have one button input which are defined in a for loop coming from backend (python). 
For example how can I do this:

```
x = clicked_object.getAttribute('btnid');
$("button[attr1=x]").css('background-color', 'green');
```

Obviously, I can write if conditions but too much programming, looking for a smarter way.

Comment: Yes, you are talking about attribute selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Could you add more context, it is not too clear what you need. Anyway, I believe, you wanted to write `$("button[attr1=" + x + "]").css('background-color', 'green');` instead of `$("button[attr1=x]").css('background-color', 'green');`. Or, if you are able to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): `$(\`button[attr1=${x}]\`).css('background-color', 'green');`

Comment: Well, I did not know if correct way is $("button[attr1=" + x + "]").css('background-color', 'green'); , you were right tho. This is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by constructing a selector that captures a particular attribute with corresponding value like so:

```js
var x = "green";
var y = "blue";
var z = "orange";

$('button[attr1="' + x + '"]').css('background-color', 'green');
$('button[attr2="' + y + '"]').css('background-color', 'blue');
$('button[attr3="' + z + '"]').css('background-color', 'orange');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button attr1="green">Button 1</button>
<button attr2="blue">Button 2</button>
<button attr3="orange">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Shidersz  on the comments offered the same solution which worked!

Comment: @Hans glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you must concat the string like this:

```
x = clicked_object.getAttribute('btnid');
$(`button[attr1='${x}']`).css('background-color', 'green');
```

Comment: Yes, i forgot the `" "` mark that wrap the value, updated

Comment: Hmm, weird, can you please try change it to single quote to see if it works ?